# Remote eror : commandtext changes are not allowed

Tags: delphi, datasnap

In DataSnap, I have a `TSQLConnection` and `TFDQuery` with `TDataSetProvider` in the server, and in the client I have `TSQLConnection` with `TDSProviderConnection` and `TClientDataSet` and `TDataSource` to show data in a `TDBGrid`.

When I want to insert into SQL from the client, I write this code:

```
ClientDataSet2.CommandText:='INSERT INTO [table_name] (param) VALUES(:v)';
ClientDataSet2.Params.ParamByName('v').AsString:='a';

ClientDataSet2.Execute;
```

When I want use this code in the client, the program shows an error:

> Remote error: commandtext changes are not allowed

How can fix this problem?

Comment: How is `ClientDataSet2` defined? You have to learn to provide those details, too. [The docs for `TCustomClientDataSet.CommandText` tell you that the provider's options need `poAllowCommandText` if you want to do this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.CommandText).